# cancel page loading state in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script which handles post form and uses document.write with event.preventDefault

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {

var form = $(this);

var request = $.ajax({
type: form.attr('method'),
url: form.attr('action'),
data: form.serialize()
}).success(function(result) {

document.write(result);

});

event.preventDefault();
});
});

</script>
```

After I press submit and call document.write - my browser enters in infinite loading page state. If I remove preventDefault() - it works, but I need it for other script part to work..

Is there a way to cancel page loading state right after document.write ?

Comment: use return false instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why `event.preventDefault` would be a problem here... Try the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize()
        }).complete(function (result) {
            $("body").html(result);
        });

    });
});
```

with `complete` instead of `success` to be sure that you haven't an error in your AJAX.